# Some confusion with cheat engine function address and IDA subrutine

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida, cheat-engine

I have found a function with Cheat Engine that I like to show in IDA:

[image]

[image]

but the function is not present in IDA.

Probably I have a bit confusion becouse I don't have experience with this tool.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Well if I understand Ultimap correctly then it show all subroutines not necessary functions. If you are expecting standard function header (`push rbp,mov rbp,rsp...`) then it can be missing there

Comment: do you known a tool that can help in this case ?

Comment: I think you're scanning a dynamic function, so that's why you won't find the same code at the same address in IDA. What I would do is attaching a debugger to that session for example x32dbg or OllyDbg then go to that function...

Another thing, maybe you want to rebase your program in IDA in Edit->Segments->Rebase Program now functions will be in the same range as Cheat Engine, for example you can do CTRL+F and find your function without the module